# Creating partition for Windows 10 with LVM

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm

Im new to ubuntu and the general linux environment, and I need some help.

I'm trying to create a partition for Windows 10 to be installed, alongside my current Ubuntu 16.04 installation.

I installed Ubuntu as a LVM partition, as i understood from the documentation that it would be easier for me to resize it at a later point, if i decided to create another partition for a different OS.

So far, i have:

Created the Win 10 USB installation media
Used system-config-lvm to resize the partition

[Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoULp.png)

As you can see, i have 100 gb unused space. How do i partition it, so the windows installation can find it during the installation process? Currently windows only registers the 3 partitions that are shown in the picture. So in a sense, i want the 100 GB unused space as a seperate partition.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu ? It sounds as if you have made space and are now asking about Windows

Comment: Windows is just the OS i intend to install on the new partition. My question relates to Ubuntu as i am asking how i make use of Ubuntu to create such a partition.

Comment: Don't. Just leave it as free space, and let windows partition it as it wants.

Comment: From the windows installation, it doesnt seem to register that my HD is split into a partition, and a 'section' of unused space. I'm pretty sure Windows will just override the entire Ubuntu installation as my HD isn't partitioned into two seperate parts consisting of 122, and 100 gb as it is shown on the attached picture..

Comment: You can't use `gparted` to view your current LVM configuration. It doesn't understand LVM.

Comment: Windows also does not know LVM, you have to have an NTFS partition outside the LVM. And one of the advantages of LVM is having it manage the entire drive. If not using entire drive, LVM may not be best choice. Also if UEFI system be sure to boot Windows in UEFI mode to install.